# How to define the classification threshold as a (hyper)parameter of a learner for tuning in mlr3 package in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, mlr3, r6

there is a function to tune threshold for say a binary classification described here: https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_pipeops_tunethreshold.html

Here's my failed attempt:

```
  RF_lrn <- lrn("classif.rfsrc", id = "rf", predict_type = "prob")
  RF_lrn$param_set$values = list(na.action = "na.impute", seed = -123)
  single_pred_rf = po("subsample", frac = 1, id = "rf_ss") %>>%
    po("learner", RF_lrn) %>>% po("tunethreshold")
```

That did not work in my mlr3 pipeline and I did not find any solution explained anywhere so here is my code:

```
   xgb_lrn <-
    lrn("classif.xgboost", id = "xgb", predict_type = "prob")
  single_pred_xgb = po("subsample", frac = 1, id = "xgb_ss") %>>%
    po("learner", xgb_lrn)
  
    lrnrs <- list(
      RF_lrn,
      xgb_lrn)
    
    lrnrs <- lapply(lrnrs, function(x) {
      GraphLearner$new(po("learner_cv", x) %>>% po("tunethreshold",
                                                   param_vals = list(
                                                     measure = "classif.prauc"
                                                   )
      ))
    })
    library("GenSA")
    lrnrs$RF_lrn <- auto_tuner(
      learner =  RF_lrn,
      search_space = ps(
        ntree = p_int(lower = 20, upper = 300),
        mtry = p_int(lower = 2, upper = 5),
        nodesize = p_int(lower = 1, upper = 7)
      ),
      resampling = rsmp("bootstrap", repeats = 2, ratio = 0.8),
      measure = msr("classif.prauc"),
      term_evals = 100,
      method = "random_search"
    )
```

which somehow works but I want the decision threshold to be tuned as a parameter the same way I tune other hyperparameters using the random search in benchmarking/cross validation. Any solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that the decision threshold is not a model parameter - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390186/is-decision-threshold-a-hyperparameter-in-logistic-regression

Comment: @rw2 If by "model" you mean only "learner" like random forest then you're right, but In machine learning you could tune the decision threshold as a free parameter which is part of the model design and that makes it well fit to the definition of a model parameter.

Comment: Have you seen the [mlr gallery example](https://mlr-org.com/gallery/2020-10-14-threshold-tuning/) for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to use `po("threshold")` instead of `po("tunethreshold")` as suggested in the comments and this [mlr gallery example](https://mlr-org.com/gallery/2020-10-14-threshold-tuning/)